# why does zabbix output UPS APC and UPS HUAWEI options differently?

Tags: monitoring, huawei-mobile-services, zabbix, apc, ups

Help to understand, please. There is a local network, there are APC and HUAWEI UPSs, the parameter "remaining battery life" is displayed differently: on APC it is displayed in the format "12 hours 30 minutes", and on HUAWEI it is displayed "46836 seconds". Why is this happening at HUAWEI? Is it possible to draw the same output as APC? Both of them store the values ​​of "remaining battery life" in integer seconds, but on the monitoring card APC displays in the format I need "hh:mm", but HUAWEI does not.